# What token standard to use for general purpose cryptocurrency

Tags: contract-design

I know there are ERC20 and ERC223 token standards. Are there any more token standards? What standart is better to use for general purpose cryptocurrency ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the only widely supported and accepted token implementation is ERC20. If you want your token to be listed on exchanges you will need to use this one.

There's still a hot ongoing debate regarding ERC20 vs ERC223: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/223

Comment: will it not be listed if i use ERC223?

Comment: You should check with the exchange where you plan to have your token trading. ERC223 is backwards-compatible with ERC20, so it should work.